# pig script to capture second unique id da12a6b2-70f7-4c07-825a-7d700519f486,633aa5cf-2551-412b-bd98-bd5d9614b288

Tags: regex, apache-pig, regex-negation

I have use

```
regex_extract(string, '(([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})|([a-fA-F0-9]{8}[a-fA-F0-9]{4}[a-fA-F0-9]{4}[a-fA-F0-9]{4}[a-fA-F0-9]{12})), 1)
```

and also string split separated by (,) to capture second among following UUIDs which are together but I don't know what am missing.
Actually I need to capture both!!

```
da1ba6b2-70f9-4c07-825a-7d700519f086,633aa5cf-2551-412b-bd96-bd5d9914b299
```

Comment: Are you trying to capture both UUIDs in one regex?

Comment: I want to capture them as two different ids.

Comment: Your regex is correct and the UUIDs match it. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Occurrence of 2 uuids is 1 percent, when it occurs I want to capture x=uuid1 and y=uuid2 else y=no value